# PHP Language Converter

Tags: php, translate

I have a script I'm using to convert English text to other spoken languages, and I have a php code handling it like so.

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "300");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('googleTranslate.class.php');
$gt = new Google_Translate_API();

$title = $gt->translate($title, "en", $lang);
$keywords = $gt->translate($keywords, "en", $lang);
$body = $gt->translate($body, "en", $lang);
```

Anyways, when I run this script, it times out before it can translate much text at all, so I was wondering if we could run one piece at a time somehow?

Also, note that the `googleTranslate.class.php` can be freely downloaded from Google Code.

Cheers

Comment: It times out while translating three pieces of text?

Comment: It can be freely downloaded, but the server-side API is no longer free: "Google Translate API v2 is now available as a paid service. The courtesy limit for existing Translate API v2 projects created prior to August 24, 2011 will be reduced to zero on December 1, 2011 (...) Google Translate API v1 will be shut off completely on the same date (December 1, 2011)": http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Turns out Google Translate API wasn't the way to go. Instead, I'm using the Bing Translate service. It also doesn't restrict me to certain lengths of text. Thanks for the help. (:

Answer (score 0):

Hm, well I think you shoulde cache results at first. Make some script witch caches translated content for needed languages. Else you fast will reach querys limit.